# Message: Undefined variable: email under Controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

I am getting Undefined Variable email under Controllers.

Controller : login.php

```
public function index() {
        $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->load->model('Login_db');
        $is_exist = $this->Login_db->isEmailExist($email);
        if ($is_exist) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('isEmailExist', 'Email Address Already Exists!');
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }


        $this->load->view('bootstrap/footer');
    }
```

Model : login_db.php

```
public function isEmailExist($email) {
        $this->db->select('user_id');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $query = $this->db->get('login');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

I have to check whether email exists are not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by checking your code i came to assume that you want to allow only the emails which is already not in table ? why have not  you validated with **is_unique** like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[login.email]');
```

or you can change the line as

```
 $this->Login_db->isEmailExist($this->input->post('email'));
```

or you should define $email before passing it / calling the function

```
$email=$this->input->post('email');
```

for custom massaging :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules( 'email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[login.email]', array( 'is_unique' => 'Email already exists' ) );
```

better you go through the manual
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'username', 'Username',
        'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.username]',
        array(
                'is_unique'     => 'Email already exists'
        )
);

Comment: I tried this, but its not showing the message. public function index() {
        $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->view('login_form');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[login.email]', array('is_unique' => 'Email already exists'));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->load->view('bootstrap/footer');
    }

Answer (score 2):

before

```
$is_exist = $this->Login_db->isEmailExist($email);
```

add this (in case of a POST request)

```
$email = $this->input->post('email');
```

or this ((in case of a GET request)

```
$email = $this->input->get('email');
```

Comment: I have cleared the error, but my login page is not displaying.

Comment: You mean, after email check you are loading login page?

Answer (score 0):

the var `$email` used here

`$is_exist = $this->Login_db->isEmailExist($email);` line 5 of index

is never isntanciate. You should instantiate it to avoir error.

Comment: But it is a function under model : login_db.php. I can't understand, how to initiate?

Comment: Yes, this function take the parameter `$email` and you give it in `index` but you give something that is never user.

`
public function index() {
        $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->load->model('Login_db');
        //$email should be initiate here 
        $is_exist = $this->Login_db->isEmailExist($email);

        $this->load->view('bootstrap/footer');
    }
`